# User of maven build spring mvc project, it's always not found jar such as spring-webmvc.jar, spring-web.jar,jstl.jar etc.

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc

I use maven to build spring mvc project, i am confused
**

1. Maven dependency:

**

```
    <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- 
        springframework
        *Core support for dependency injection, transaction management,
        web applications, data access, messaging, testing and more.
     -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- JSTL 支持 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jstl</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- 
        Spring webmvc 
        include spring-web-4.0 and spring-webmvc    
    -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

and i import some necessary jar such as slf4j.jar, dom4j.jar, stander.jar etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
C:\Users\yourusername\.m2\repository
```

This is the location for maven repository.check if your jar files are there or not.

Comment: please go through once with this link as well.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8814110/first-steps-with-maven-for-my-spring-mvc-app?rq=1

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I checked, jar files are there, i placed them into /WEB_INF/lib, it works. Next time, I will try "mvn clean install". Thank you again!

Comment: could you please accept this as your answer if its solves your problem